# whats the bug in this futoshiki game code openMP tasks?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, openmp

I am trying to code the futoshiki puzzle game in parallel using c++ and openMP. Futoshiki is a sudoku like puzzle game. I coded the sequential version and it works fine but my parallel code ends earlier than its supposed to, i think the tasked threads crash at some point so the rest of my code doesn't execute but I don't get an error output. Is this normal or am I misunderstanding my error.

DFS is the function thats supposed to solve the problem, and after all the function calls I print something depending on output being correct or wrong, but program ends before it prints anything. I can't understand what the problem is.
My code is below:

```
    bool dfs(int** matrix,vector<vector<int>> & visited,vector<vector<bool>> & constraintsUp,vector<vector<bool>> & constraintsDown,int &X,int &Y)
   {

    pair<int,int> xy=getUnassignedLocation(visited,X,Y);
    if(xy==GRID_FULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    if(HELPPLS)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int x=xy.first;
    int y=xy.second;

    for(int it=1;it<=SIZE;++it)
    {
        if(isSafe(it,x,y,visited,constraintsUp,constraintsDown))
        {
            visited[x][y]=it;
            if(DEPTHCOUNT)
            {
                DEPTHCOUNT--;
                bool check=false;
                #pragma omp task default(shared) shared(visited,constraintsUp,constraintsDown)
                {
                    int **newMatrix;
                    copy(newMatrix,matrix);
                    vector<vector<int>> newVisited(visited);
                    vector<vector<bool>>newConstraintsUp(constraintsUp);
                    vector<vector<bool>>newConstraintsDown(constraintsDown);
                    int xx=x;
                    int yy=y;
                    HELPPLS=HELPPLS||dfs(newMatrix,newVisited,newConstraintsUp,newConstraintsDown,xx,yy);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (dfs(matrix,visited,constraintsUp,constraintsDown,x,y))
                {   HELPPLS=true;
                    if(v)
                    {
                        temp=visited;
                        v=false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
            visited[x][y]=BLANK;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `copy(newMatrix,matrix);` -- There is no size information given to `copy` as to how big the matrix is.  All you're passing are `int**`, and that does not give any information to `copy` as to how much to copy.  Unless the size information inside of `copy` is gotten by some other outside function, it is useless.

Comment: It is given with a global variable called SIZE